# web3j - Java - Resolve ENS Name to Contract Address

Tags: web3j, ens

I am trying to Resolve my ENS Name to the corresponding Contract Address. But so far I get the error

```
org.web3j.tx.exceptions.ContractCallException: Empty value (0x) returned from contract
```

I am using web3j version 4.5.11 which should support ENS Names.

So far I found out that the ENS Name ethereum.eth is being resolved but other ENS Name throw an error.

My guess is that the Public Resolver from web3j is wrong or out-dated.

I use the Public Resolver: 0x42D63ae25990889E35F215bC95884039Ba354115

Here is my code:

```
Web3j web3j = getWeb3J();

    Credentials credentials = getCredentials();
    EnsResolver ensResolver = new EnsResolver(web3j);

    String contractAddress = ensResolver.resolve(ensName);
```

Comment: Did you manage how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest docs:

The ENS registry is deployed at 0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e. This same address is used across Mainnet, Ropsten, Rinkeby and Goerli.

Check out this: [docs.ens.domains/ens-deployments](https://docs.ens.domains/ens-deployments). Hope this helps.